# C++ Type traits in constructor causing error

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I want to have a constructor that takes a single argument and is only enabled if the type of that argument has a member type `::t` which must  be a subtype of some other type. I am using type traits for this and the code looks like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Y{};

struct X{
    //Only allow if T has a type member T::t which is a subtype of Y
    template <typename T>
    X(T* t, std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Y, typename T::t>::value, int>::type e = 0){}
};
```

However, g++ complains the following:

```
test/test.cpp:8:75: error: ‘std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Y, typename T::t>::value, int>::type’ is not a type
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a `typename` to `std::enable_if<...>::type` to resolve this...

Comment: Oh, right, since ::type depends on a template parameter, I have to use the typename prefix, right?

Comment: Exactly. The another level of indirection in the analyzed type (= `T::t`) will cause problems too, I suppose.

Comment: why? I used the typename keyword here.